# Shape a FOR XML query against an xml column to include attribute in root

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Given a table with an xml column:

```
/*
CREATE TABLE #test (id int, content xml);
INSERT INTO #test VALUES (1, N'<i>abc</i>'),(1, N'<i>def</i>');
*/
```

I can create an xml document for downstream deserialization easily:

```
  SELECT content AS [*]
    FROM #test T
 FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('root')
```

yielding:

```
/*
<root>
  <i>abc</i>
  <i>def</i>
</root>
*/
```

However, I would like to add an attribute to 'root', with the ideal output of:

```
/*
<root tag="42">
  <i>abc</i>
  <i>def</i>
</root>
*/
```

So far, all I can manage to accomplish this is adding an additional level to the xml structure:

```
  SELECT 42 AS [@tag],
         (SELECT content AS [*]  FROM #test T FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE) AS [*]
 FOR XML PATH('extra'), ROOT('root')
```

yielding:

```
/*
 <root>
  <extra tag="42">
    <i>abc</i>
    <i>def</i>
  </extra>
</root>
*/
```

because

```
  SELECT 42 AS [@tag],
         (SELECT content AS [*]  FROM #test T FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE) AS [*]
 FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('root')
```

is not allowable syntax.
Are there any suggestions for adding an attribute to the root node without adding an extra level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, answer seems super simple now, but took several iterations to figure out:

```
  SELECT 42 AS [@tag],
         (SELECT content AS [*]  FROM #test T FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE) AS [*]
 FOR XML PATH('root')
```

I didn't realize the FOR XML syntax could leave out *both* the ROOT and TYPE specifiers, especially since doing so would have only yielded a set of fragments for the original query.